# NodeJS Request how to send multipart/form-data POST request

Tags: node.js, request, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a POST request to an API with an image in the request. I'm doing this with the request module but everything I try it isn't working. My current code:

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://api.LINK.com/file",
    port: 443,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    form : {
        "image" : fs.readFileSync("./images/scr1.png")
    }
};

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(body);
});
```

But request uses `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for some reason... How can I fix this?

Answer (score 29):

You need to supply the `formData` option (not the `form` option) and request will send `multipart/form-data` data using the `form-data` library:

```
const request = require("request");
const fs = require("fs");

const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://api.LINK.com/file",
    port: 443,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("user:secret")
    },
    formData : {
        "image" : fs.createReadStream("./images/scr1.png")
    }
};

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(body);
});
```

It will set the Content-Type header for you. See the [documentation](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads).

Comment: I am getting bellow message for the above approach - 

Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1257)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:734)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:566)

Comment: @DebashisChowdhury I guess you already figured it out but it seems that the url yor are calling has an invalid certificate (self signed or expired probably). Try calling it without https or if it's your own, you could use a certificate from LetsEncrypt

Comment: @JoColina, i solved the issue. instead of **port** attribute, i used **strictSSL: false**. Then it's working.

Answer (score 19):

Annoyed that almost all example solutions to this problem include third-party modules. I know it's often easier to simply include a module and copy/paste a code example but really shouldn't need one for basic HTTP concepts like this. Adding modules can quickly increase your footprint in cloud environments like AWS lambda where total solution file-size can drastically impact run-time performance. I found this helpful example here,

https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/07/27/multipart-post-request-using-node.js/

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var upfile = 'sample.zip';
fs.readFile(upfile, function(err, content){
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
    var metadata = {
        token: "### access token ###",
        channels: "sample",
        filename: "samplefilename",
        title: "sampletitle",
    };
    var url = "https://slack.com/api/files.upload";
    var boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    var data = "";
    for(var i in metadata) {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(metadata, i)) {
            data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
            data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + i + "\"; \r\n\r\n" + metadata[i] + "\r\n";
        }
    };
    data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + upfile + "\"\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type:application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    var payload = Buffer.concat([
            Buffer.from(data, "utf8"),
            new Buffer(content, 'binary'),
            Buffer.from("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n", "utf8"),
    ]);
    var options = {
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary},
        body: payload,
    };
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Hope it's helpful to someone else!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the tradeoff is hard to maintain, brittle code. So choose your path wisely based on your needs.

Comment: Your solution uses the `request` module which includes support for form data.  It would do this for you, if you would allow it, with no new dependencies other than the ones you've already included.

Comment: This is gold. I wouldn't consider it brittle. People think of code like this amorphous magical infinitely flexible thing that can be endlessly refactored.

Comment: If your file contains the line "`--xxxxxxxxxx`" this code will send a broken HTTP request because it leaves implementing generating a random boundary to the person copy/pasting it.

Answer (score 9):

With `request` module being [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142), consider using [`form-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) (the only dependecy; small package that takes care of ugly low level details like computing unique boundary strings) and core `http(s)` module instead.

It's a little bit more verbose but you get smaller production builds, which is always good, even more so in serverless environments where it may reduce cold start time.

```js
// abstract and promisify actual network request
async function makeRequest(formData, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = formData.submit(options, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(new Error(err.message))
      }

      if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
        return reject(new Error(`HTTP status code ${res.statusCode}`))
      }

      const body = []
      res.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk))
      res.on('end', () => {
        const resString = Buffer.concat(body).toString()
        resolve(resString)
      })
    })
  })
}

const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('comment', 'Some note attached to the submitted file')
formData.append('image', fs.createReadStream('./images/logo.png'))

const options = {
  host: 'postman-echo.com',
  path: '/post',
  method: 'POST',
  protocol: 'https:', // note : in the end
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic some-token-here`,
  },
}

const res = await makeRequest(formData, options)
```

Update addressing the production/lambda build size. Answers that use the `request` package add [3.84mb](https://packagephobia.com/result?p=request) of footprint. The `form-data` library used here is [304kb](https://packagephobia.com/result?p=form-data).

Comment: I was posting a file from node (zapier actually) to a PHP script but it turned out that there is some issue in PHP that when you post multipart/form-data using 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' PHP just doesn't populate neither the $_POST nor $_FILES variables so you get nothing. However, everything works if you use the "Content-Length" header alternative which FormData (the form-data NPM package) uses in its formData.submit method. 3 days on this issue, finally thanks to this code solved! Thanks. You can submit the form data with other modules but they don't use the Content-Lenght header, careful.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to build a working example in typescript with no external dependencies.  I would still recommend the solution [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64885619/1543183)  but figured this might be helpful for others.  The only external dependency here is [mime-types](https://packagephobia.com/result?p=mime-types) to set the content-type header but if you know the content type being uploaded in advance this could be removed, making the solution completely dependency free.

implementation:

```
/* eslint-disable prefer-template */
import http from 'http';
import fs from 'fs';
import mime from 'mime-types';

interface FileObject extends Record<string, string> {
  fileName: string,
}

const buildFormInputFields = (fileObj: FileObject) => Object.entries(fileObj).map(
  ([key, value], index) => {
    const pairStr = `name="${key}"; ${key}="${value}"`;
    return index === Object.keys(fileObj).length - 1 ? pairStr : `${pairStr};`;
  },
).join(' ');

const createFileRequest = (
  fileObj: FileObject,
  data: Buffer,
  boundary: string,
) => {
  const inputFields = buildFormInputFields(fileObj);
  const { fileName } = fileObj;
  const mimeType = mime.lookup(fileName);
  if (!mimeType) throw new Error(`invalid mime type for file ${fileName}`);
  const header = (
    `--${boundary}\r\n`
    + `Content-Disposition: form-data; ${inputFields}`
    + '\r\n'
    + `Content-Type: ${mime.lookup(fileObj.fileName)}`
    + '\r\n\r\n'
  );
  return Buffer.concat([
    Buffer.from(header, 'utf-8'),
    data,
    Buffer.from('\r\n', 'utf-8'),
  ]);
};

const buildRequestOptions = (boundary: string, length: number) => (
  {
    // your host here
    host: 'localhost',
    // your port here
    port: 8088,
    // your endpoint here
    path: '/api/v1/files',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundary}`,
      'Content-Length': length,
      Accept: '*/*',
    },
  }
);

const sendFileUploadRequest = (files: FileObject[], boundary: string) => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    const fileBodies = files.map((fileObj) => {
      const { fileName } = fileObj;
      const data = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/${fileName}`);
      return createFileRequest(fileObj, data, boundary);
    });

    const footer = `--${boundary}--`;

    const body = Buffer.concat([
      ...fileBodies,
      Buffer.from(footer, 'utf-8'),
    ]);

    const options = buildRequestOptions(boundary, body.length);

    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(`status: ${res.statusCode}`);

      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
        resolve(null);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e);
      console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });
    req.write(body);
    req.end();
  },
);
```

example script using this:

```
(async () => {
  const files: FileObject[] = [
    {
      fileName: 'test1.txt',
      foo: 'bar',
    },
    {
      fileName: 'test2.txt',
      foo: 'bar',
    },
  ];
  const boundary = '----FOOBAR';
  await sendFileUploadRequest(files, boundary);
})();
```