# How make a post multipart/form-data to a another localhost server with nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, http

I have an application that needs to be make a post with an image. This application is background running on the ip 127.0.0.1 in my own computer. I've tried to many things to make this, but nothing works.

My actualy code is bellow:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');

module.exports = function () { 
    var formData = {
        pict: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/tempCaptcha.png')
    };
    request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1/', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) { return 'error'; }
        return body;
    });

}
```

I have an form to manually post the image on then, code bellow:

```
<form 
 method="post" 
 action="http://127.0.0.1/" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file"   name="pict">
 &nbsp;Name:&nbsp;(optional)&nbsp;<input type="text"   name="captcha_platform">
 <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

When i send via insomnia i get the correct answer "unknown".

[image: error print]

This is the "res.send()" of the request.

[image: res send of the request]

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"? What happens instead? And what do you mean by "another localhost server"? There can only be one single webserver per host/port combination

Comment: @NicoHaase when i post with Insomnia i get the correct answer from this "server", is an exe file. Hes using another port. The insomnia return to me a three red dots, when i return the request all data is ok, but the image dont append to the header request. I will send more information to you see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS Request how to send multipart/form-data POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053193/nodejs-request-how-to-send-multipart-form-data-post-request)

Comment: @Boaz is not a duplicate because my request is in my localhost server, not in a third API.

Comment: @FelipeGuimarães The answer you’re looking for is in the duplicate.