# Save image with express sent by node script

Tags: node.js, express

i'm trying to send an image with this nodejs script:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var post_options = {
    host: '192.168.43.193',
    path: '/testAPI/upload_img_mt',
    port: 80,
    timeout: 120000,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}

var sender = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    if (res.statusCode < 399) {
        var text = ""
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            text += chunk
        })
        res.on('end', function(data) {
            console.log(text)
        })
    } else {
        console.log("ERROR", res.statusCode)
    }
})

var POST_DATA = 'data={['
POST_DATA += fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/alessio/Documents/FX/screenshot.png").toString()
POST_DATA += ']}'
console.log(POST_DATA)
sender.write(POST_DATA)
sender.end()
```

The code for server that will be save the image is this:

```
router.post('/upload_img_mt', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body.data);
    fs.writeFile('downloaded.png', req.body.data, '', function (err){ console.log(err) });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The problem is that the image is not a valid png and the size of image is not correct.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053193/nodejs-request-how-to-send-multipart-form-data-post-request

Comment: This solution don't work for me.. the problem is the express code ( server-side ) and not in the send script. When log the **req.body.data** the image is present.

Comment: I cannot test this fully now but I think the problem is in the writeFile method line. There you need to either pass a callback or await the promise that method returns: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: but the callback is only for manage the errors.. can you explain your idea with an example?

Comment: @Mattia API doesn't need to wait until file is written. Why are you replacing some characters from string encoded image?

Comment: maybe is an error.. i have copied the code but not work anyway also without that part.