# Image is not uploading using request.post getting undefined value

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

```js
const formData = req.file('image')

const options = {
      url: 'myurl'',
      method: 'POST',
      formData : formData
}

request.post(options, async function(err,result,body){
    if(err)
    {
      res.json({
               success: false, 
               message: "There are some error occured in file upload"
              });
    }
    else
    {
      res.json({success: true});
    }
});
```

I am trying to upload an image using request.post but it does not allow me to upload the image please guide how can I fix it

Please guide

Edit1:

1. I am using ejs as frontend.
2. Trying to send that uploaded image from one server(example1.com) to other server(example2.com).
3. Server1(example1.com) is powered with sails.js.

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" as header. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053193/nodejs-request-how-to-send-multipart-form-data-post-request This post will help.
Also request npm package is deprecated, use axios instead.

Comment: I checked Ivan answered he used { "image" : fs.createReadStream("./images/scr1.png ") but we want to upload how to pass requested file on it ?

Comment: Let me get a clear picture first. 
1) Are you using "ejs" for front-end or some other frameworks like "react".
2) You are using fs module, so it looks like the above code is written in backend(sails.js).
3) If yes, where are your requesting the post call. Are you sending an image from one backend source(example1.com) to other backend source(example2.com)?

Comment: Yes sails js is being used here and ejs yes we are sending one backend to other backend using microservervice

Answer (score 0):

1. Use enctype='multipart/form-data' in your ejs form.
2. Since you are sending that image from one backend(example1.com) to other backend(example2.com) using microservervice, first save that image in your first backend(example1.com)
3. Then pass that image path(example1.com/images/img1.jpg) to the post request. For example

   postdata = {
   imageurl: 'example1.com/images/img1.jpg',
   imagesize: '1200',
   }
4. Only example1.com can be able to access your local image path(For example: c://temp/img1.jpg). So you should upload that image in your server 1(example1.com)
5. Alternatively convert the image to blob type and send. This way you don't need to save the image in server1(example1.com).

Comment: is it not possible to save it directory to other server ?

Comment: You can convert the image into blob type