# How to send a file as multipart/form-data from node.js when it is uploaded from client as multipart/form-data already?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multipartform-data, multer, form-data

I have a NodeJs/React application. The use case is to upload a file, get it scanned by a third party API and then if successful save the same. We cannot save file before scan is done.

We are uploading the file as multipart-formdata from react using a fetch method. Once file is received in Node.js to access the file and check for filesize and type we are using multer as below.

```
  router.post("/upload", upload.any("fieldname"), (req, res) => {
    scanFiles(req.files[0])
      .then((data) => {
        global.logger.info("scanned successfully.....");
        res.status(200);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        global.logger.info("scan api ended with errors", err);
        res.status(400).send({ error: err.message })
      });
  });
```

Now the scan api expects us to send the file as multipart form data as well. In this scenario how to use the field received in req.files[0] to append to formData. I tried the below but its failing

```
const formData = new FormData();
try {
  formData.append("file", file, "sample_pdf");
} catch (err) {
  global.logger.error("Form data ended with errors", err);
}
```

I am getting an error while trying to do the same. It seems the second parameter to formData.append expects a file stream but instead getting file object from the req.files[0]. In this scenario do we need to convert the file data to a file stream?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS Request how to send multipart/form-data POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053193/nodejs-request-how-to-send-multipart-form-data-post-request).  You're definitely taking the right approach: use multer; use POST.  This example might also help: [Handling File Uploads in Node.js with Express and Multer](https://stackabuse.com/handling-file-uploads-in-node-js-with-expres-and-multer/).  If you're getting an error: *PLEASE COPY/PASTE THE EXACT ERROR MESSAGE!*

Comment: It doesn't actually. I am able to upload files using multer but once we have the file at Node js level we want to send it to another API that is also expecting it to be sent as multipart/form-data. The problem is how to append the file in formData.append. We can do this generally with fileReadSync which creates a BLOB but if the file is already uploaded as multipart/form-data there is no clarity on how to change that to a BLOB type

Comment: It really helps when you take the trouble to copy/paste an *EXACT ERROR msg*, instead of a vague "I am getting an error...".  That gives us something "definite" we can Google for.  But I understand your question is that you want to forward the binary data *DIRECTLY* from the request object (presumably a "Blob" type), without saving to a "file" first.  Correct?

Comment: @paulsm: Yes. I cannot save the file as it may have some malware and instead pass the file object as BLOB by appending it to a form-data instead.

I did not want to put in the error message because it was vague and could not get anything when I googled it myself but you are correct should have added the error message.

Answer (score 0):

formData.append expect file as Blob
I don't understand type of req.files[0]

but if this file have method .arrayBuffer(), you can try it

```
file.arrayBuffer().then((array) => {
    formData.append('file', new Blob([array]), 'simple_pdf.pdf');
});
```

Comment: I can try that. For your clarification, when I use multer it makes the file uploaded to Node.js available in req.files property. I am not sure what is the type of this but I can check the same.

Comment: Its just a file object and I don't see the arrayBuffer method inside it. here is the object structure


fieldname:'file'
encoding:'7bit'
filename:'421af876d134e34199e714ba72b7d744'
mimetype:'application/pdf'
originalname:'sample_pdf.pdf'
path:'uploads\\421af876d134e34199e714ba72b7d744'
destination:'uploads/'
size:3028
__proto__:Object

Comment: I confirmed that file does not have an array buffer property so getting an error in catch block that file.arrayBuffer is not a function