# How to fix imgur api error status 400, 417 errors

Tags: javascript, imgur

While uploading pictures using the Imgur API,
some pictures are not uploaded and
returns status 400 or 417 errors.

```
{
  status: 400,
  success: false,
  data: {
    error: "We don't support that file type!",
    request: '/3/upload'
}
{
  status: 417,
  success: false,
  data: {
    error: 'Internal expectation failed',
    request: '/3/upload',
    method: 'POST'
  }
}
```

This error was fixed upon launching the console.
But every time I upload a picture I have to restart the console. How may I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[417](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/417)** error states that the Imgur CDN was expecting a file type such as .png, .mp4, .gif, etc. You may view the supported file types [here](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000083326-What-files-can-I-upload-What-is-the-size-limit-).

The **[400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)** indicates an improper / bad request , while requesting the API for a `POST` type request you must know how to properly request it, you may refer to the proper method [here](https://api.imgur.com/#:%7E:text=To%20use%20Imgur%27s%20API%20commercially,api.imgur.com%2F).

Comment: But when I restart the console it works very well. 
Also, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: That could be purely due to a bad API request, I recommend either using [`node-imgur`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur) for easy uploads **or** studying the documentation properly and rewrite your code.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Your **"Account"** and your **"Application**" are distinct entities.
If you try to upload to an album on your account, thinking your application has access rights to it because they are tied to the same email, you'll probably get the 417 error.

Also, it seems that imgur validates the .PNG file before validating access rights.

I have concluded that as you are trouble shooting , this is a rough gauge of "how close to success" you are:

1: **VERY CLOSE** :
"Internal Expectation Failed"
Your .PNG payload within the form-data is probably correct.

2: **COLDER** :
"We Don't Support That File Type"
You probably corrupted your .PNG binary file when attempting to concat it into the "form-data" payload.

3: **COLDEST** :
"bad request"
You messed up real bad.

If you are rolling your own "multi-part form-data" like I did, one of the posters here has a good low-level example that does **NOT** use 3rd party libraries:
[NodeJS Request how to send multipart/form-data POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053193/)

Your payload is constructed something like this:

```
payload=Buffer.concat([
    Buffer.from( formdata_string_top    , "utf8"   ) 
,   Buffer.from( png_binary_file        , "binary" ) 
,   Buffer.from( final_formdata_boundary, "utf8"   ) 
]);;
```

You might be tempted to do this , because it is readable in your
logs, but it **WILL_CORRUPT_YOUR_BINARY_FILE**

```
payload=Buffer.concat([
    Buffer.from( formdata_string_top    , "utf8"   ) 
,   Buffer.from( png_binary_file        , "binary" ) 
,   Buffer.from( final_formdata_boundary, "utf8"   ) 
]).toString( "utf8" );
```